# Using regex with python re.match

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python and have a question about using regex on strings. Currently I have:

```
def find_ips(ip):
    ip_str = '\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b'
    p = re.compile(ip_str)

    m = p.match(ip)
    if m:
        print 'match found'
    else:
        print 'no match'

    global find_addr
    find_addr = p.match(ip)
    return find_addr

find_ips('this is an ip 127.0.0.1 10.0.10.5')
print find_addr
```

This returns 'no match'. I'm not seeing what i'm missing so far. I am trying to extract the ip addresses out of this string, but first I have to find them. Using a regex editor I can use that same line to discover those IPs. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Quick note: Your regex syntax is incorrect, remove the `/` delimiters and the `g` modifier. And use `search` instead of match.

Comment: all your string has that format ? "this is an ip xxxxxx"

Comment: `\b` is an escape sequence. use a raw string, or escape the backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.match()` matches from the beginning of the string, I would use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) here if you want to match all. Also it's good practice to use raw string notation with your pattern.

```
>>> import re
>>> def find_ips(str):
...     m = re.findall(r'\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b', str)
...     return ', '.join(m)
...
>>> print find_ips('this is an ip 127.0.0.1 10.0.10.5')
127.0.0.1, 10.0.10.5
```

Answer (score 2):

`re.match` only finds a match if it is at the beginning of the string.  `re.search` will look in the entire string for a match.

Also, it's usually a good idea to use raw strings when making regex:

```
ip_str = r'\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b'
#        ^
```

---

On a slightly unrelated note:

```
find_ips('this is an ip 127.0.0.1 10.0.10.5')
print find_addr
```

is a bit kludgy.  Making use of the return value in the caller is much better than doing funky stuff with globals:

```
print find_ips('...')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from re import findall                                            

# The string to be checked.
string = 'this is a string 126.32.13.1 with ips in 132.31.3.1 it'

# Print the matches of the regex in the string.
print findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', string)    

# Output
# ['126.32.13.1', '132.31.3.1']
```